# Allow internal urls while on VPN and proxy

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox-networking

I am currently using Ubuntu guest in Windows host using virtual box.I enabled proxy on ubuntu, when I am connected to office network or on VPN, I can't reach internal company urls from guest. I get `Access Denied (policy_denied)`
Is there a away rules that I can create so that I can reach the internal URL's

Answer (score 0):

The IP address of the guest operating system is  blocked by company firewall.  Change your Ubuntu's IP address to in a allowed IP range